# If Submission is successful how do I get the div to dissapear?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

If the form is submitted and is successful it displays an alert saying "It was a success" rather than that I want the div to just disappear..

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(":submit").click(function() {

            var name= $('#name').val();
            var email= $('#email').val();

            var varData= 'name=' + name + '&email' + email;
            console.log(varData);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "form.php",
                data: varData,
                success: function() {
                    // needs changing
                    alert("It was success");
                }
            })

        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="container.form">
                <hr>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="NewsLetter1" />
                <br>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="NewsLetter2" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                <hr>
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?php     
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];    
mail($email, $name, "Thank you")    
?>
```

Comment: Problem #1 : you are missing an equal sign after "&email" : `var varData= 'name=' + name + '&email' + email;` . Problem #2 : you are using "get" parameters, so you should use `type:"GET"` instead of `type:"POST"`.

Comment: $('#container.form').hide() ?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how do I make the div 'container.form' disappear if the submission is successful?

Comment: For use in javascript I would *highly* suggest not naming your div `container.form`, because `$("#container.form")` would mean `<div id="container"><div class="form"></div></div>`

Comment: @JasonP The question can be guessed with the title + the beginning of the post, that's why I answered

Comment: @rap-2-h I know, I was being intentionally dense. Posts should have a question, and "write this code for me" isn't the kind of question (statement?) SO exists for, especially when 20 minutes at learn.jquery.com would give OP the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of issues here.

Firstly you should hook to the `submit()` event of the parent `form` and cancel it using `event.preventDefault()`. Your current code will ignore the AJAX request and submit the form in the standard manner.

Secondly your querystring is not formatted correctly - you're missing an `=`. It's better practice to provide an object to the `data` property of `$.ajax` partly for this reason (to avoid typos) and also because jQuery will encode any required characters for you.

To solve your actual issue, call `hide()` or `fadeOut()` on the `div` you want to hide. You'll need to escape the `.` in the `id` otherwise it will be interpreted as a class selector. Try this:

```
<div id="container.form">
    <form method="post" action="form.php">
        <hr>
        <label for="name">Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="NewsLetter1" /><br>
        <label for="email">Email</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="NewsLetter2" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <hr>
    </form>
</div>
```

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: this.method,
        url: this.action,
        data: {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val()
        },
        success: function() {
            $('#container\\.form').hide();
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: 'email: $('#email').val();' shouldn't this have a comma?

Comment: My mistake - the semi colon shouldn't be there at all. Answer updated

Comment: it redirects me to a php page and doesn't go back? is this something to do with the action on the form?

Comment: You're missing the document.ready handler code around the `form.submit` handler. All the jQuery code on your page can be placed in a single `$(document).ready(fn)` code block, instead of multiple ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace this:

```
success: function() {
    // needs changing
    alert("It was success");
}
```

With this:

```
success: function() {       
    $('#container\\.form').hide();
}
```

Comment: `#container.form` will look for an element with an `id` of 'container' and a `class` of 'form'

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks! Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

1) Better to use < form > elements, and use event onSubmit. That is true way.

```
$("#formid").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "form.php",
        data:  $("#formid").serialize(),
        success: function() {
            // needs changing
            alert("It was success");
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a dot in your id attribute, and dots are used for class filtering, you should escape that dot:

```
success: function() {
     $('#container\\.form').hide();
}
```